# cannot sync shared folder using VMware windows 7 as main OS and centOS 6 as guest

Tags: windows, hadoop, centos, virtual-machine, vmware

I create the shared file as suggested, there is no error showing up but then in `mnt/hgfs`that is the suggested path nothing shows up. I tried to follow the first solution in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74825/why-dont-shared-files-show-up-in-hgfs) but it says command not found. I am really new to this so any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I am trying to use the single node VM on cloudera and I really cannot get the shared folder to work, I looked everywhere to no avail, for me it does not work for the 4.8 and the 5.3. I cannot imagine I am the only one with this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you provided you need to install/update VMWare-tools on the guest.

Check out these links.

[Verifying a VMware Tools build version](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003947)

[Installing VMware Tools in a Linux virtual machine using Red Hat Package Manager](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018392)

[Installing VMware Tools in a Linux virtual machine using a Compiler](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1018414)

Hope this helps,

Deeh

Comment: Hey no i do not think VMWare Tools is the problem since I can drag files from windows host to the guest. moreover i cannot install it, under Player -> Manager i can only cancel the VMWare tools installation, any other option why this might be?

Comment: The right solution was to update VmWare Tools as Deeh suggested, I just was not able to do so because I was not deleting a folder named VmWare-Tools under `/usr/lib` referring to the old installation

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same issue. Found a solution and able to share files between the host Windows 7 and guest Linux machine

Check if the Sharing is enabled: Control panel --> Network and Internet --> Network and sharing center --> Change advanced settings --> Home or work --> Under Public folder shared check the box "Turn on network sharing so that anyone with network access can read and write"

Then share the folder --> with everyone read/write
Open the properies of the shared folder --> share --> check the path **//hp-pc**/FolderName

the in Linux/ubunto VM --> Open the root -- On the tab click on file "connect to server" --> add folder name , Username as "hp-pc" (Admin for that host pc), WORKGROUP and connect.
Give password.

Then folder can be viewed in VM

Regards,
Hems

Comment: i follow you until you check the path, which path is the one the folder is supposed to be shared with?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time to solve the same problem in UBUNTU. It was a pain. BUT!
I found the solution [here](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?20022-HGFS-not-working-on-Kali-Linux-Shared-Folders-on-VMWare&p=30535#post30535)

```
1 - Run: apt-get install dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential psmisc
2 - Run: git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git
3 - Run: cd vmware-tools-patches/patches
4 - Remove every folder except "vmhgfs".
5 - Get the last version of VMwareTools clicking on VMWare Bar > VM > Install/Reinstall VMWare Tools. It will open a virtual CD containing the "tar" file.
6 - Copy VMwareTools-9.2.4-1398046.tar.gz to "vmware-tools-patches" folder.
7 - On "vmware-tools-patches" folder, run: ./untar-and-patch-and-compile.sh
```

Comment: this question was for fedora, your commands are ubuntu (i guess).

Comment: Yep, I worked with ubuntu. I guess in Fedora it's about to be the same. But I really spent a lot of time to share a folder in both linux & windows via vmware. Tried to find the best question on stackoverflow to share the solution with others.